# Category based WCF service notifications

Tags: wcf, push-notification, duplex

How to achieve category-based WCF notifications?

I want to send notifications to clients who seeks for particular products category instead of notifying all.

Is it possible if please share the algorithm or way to achieve please.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: You're looking for a publish-subscribe model.  Take a look at this [Topic-based publish/subscribe design pattern implementation in c#-Part II (Using WCF).](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34333/Topic-based-publish-subscribe-design-pattern-imple)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have implemented it using Signal R instead of WCF.